# How can I get rid of the text field when using jQuery.terminal with Next JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js, jquery-terminal

I am trying to use jquery.terminal within a Next.js app.

This is my terminal component:

```
    import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
    
    import $ from 'jquery';
    import 'jquery.terminal';
    
    function Terminal() {
      useEffect(() => {
        $('#terminal').terminal(function(command, terminal) {
          // your code here
        }, );
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <div id="terminal"></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default Terminal;
```

And this is how it looks like:

[image: jquery.terminal with text area for input]

My question is how can I get rid of this text area and have the input direct at the ">"?

Comment: You need to include CSS file.

Comment: what css element do I have to look at to change this?

Comment: You need to import the CSS file. Right now you don't use any CSS. You need to add `import 'jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.css';`